# Elasticsearch Multi Get with Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

Can you use the Multi Get API with aggregation/facets?

For example, if I store documents called Shapes and I have 500 shape_ids, each shape has a side_count and I'd like to find out the average side_count of that list of shape_ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A get request is very different compared to a search request. A get doesn't imply any query as given index, type and id (or routing) of a document we know where it is (which shard), thus the document is retrieved from the interesting shard and returned. Multi get is just a variation that does the same with multiple documents, in a more optimized way as it groups get requests per shards, minimizing the network roundtrips. Note also that get is real-time, as documents can either be retrieved from the lucene index or from the elasticsearch transaction log if not available yet for search.

Aggregations require a search request and cannot be run on top of documents returned by get requests. You might be able to achieve the same result though using the search api and the [ids filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-filter.html) instead of the multi get.